# Match the either middle of a word or the entire word in regex

Tags: regex, bash, macos, if-statement

I want to match both `proposition` and the `sit` in the middle of the word. How can I do this with regex?

I know you can do something like `^(proposition|sit)$` but I'm wondering if there's a different way.

Here would be the allowed strings (not treated as a multiline entry):

```
proposition
sit
```

And here would be some disallowed strings also not treated as multiline entries:

```
Proposition
position
SIT
stuffit_archive.sit
proposition 65
```

I'm using an if statement in bash 3.2.57(1)-release under 10.11.6 El Capitan.

Comment: "sit" as substring of "propsition"? Please give an example of the case for "middle of word".

Comment: So you already have a solution that works the way you want? Why are you looking for different ways of doing it?

Comment: @karakfa If the user inputs a value and it has to match either `proposition` or `sit`.

Comment: @thatotherguy I am just trying to learn regex and I'm doing some experimenting. I thought there would be something like `propo(sit)?ion` but for obvious reasons that doesn't work in the way I need it to.

Comment: The way _you need it_ is unclear. You're trying to make nuclear medicine out of regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `^.*(proposition|sit).*$`. Also, make sure that the command in you call this regex is set to case insensitive.

Comment: it should be *case-sensitive*, not the other way.

Comment: `position` is one of his (her) examples that shouldn't be found.